# react-hook-form 'on Submit' function code is not executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

If a form submits successfully, I want the `onSubmit` function to be called.

The validation is working correctly, but the `onSubmit` function is not being called and there are no errors showing so I can not figure out the issue.

This is the `onSubmit` function causing the problem:

```
 const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Props> = (data) => console.log("testing");
```

and I am calling it with this line:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} ref={form}>
```

I am using the react-hook-form library and yup to validate forms. I am also using react, and typescript.

This is the rest of the code:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { string, number, object, InferType } from "yup";


type Props = InferType<typeof schema>;

const schema = object({
  firstName: string().required("First name is required"),
});

function FormEmail() {
  const form = useRef(null);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<Props>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

 const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Props> = (data) => console.log("testing");

return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} ref={form}>

            <h3>First Name</h3>
            <input
              id="firstName"
              type="text"
              {...register("firstName")}
            />
            <span className="error">{errors?.firstName?.message}</span>

            <button className="" type="submit">
              Submit
            </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FormEmail;
```

[docs for handleSubmit]https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/handlesubmit/#main

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use **handleSubmit** in **onSubmit** and you have some problem in the code...
so this code will be working with you

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { string, number, object, InferType } from "yup";

function onSubmit(values: Props) {}

const schema = object({
  firstName: string().required("First name is required")
});

type Props = InferType<typeof schema>;

function FormEmail() {
  const form = useRef(null);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm<Props>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Props> = (data) => console.log("testing");

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} ref={form}>
        <h3>First Name</h3>
        <input id="firstName" type="text" {...register("firstName")} />
        <span className="error">{errors?.firstName?.message}</span>

        <button className="" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FormEmail;
```

Comment: thaks. you save my day bro

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good, but you the `sendEmail` function is registered to form submit instead of the testing one.

It should be just like you wrote it in the smaller snippet (this works for me):

```js
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} ref={form}>
```